# Run sudo commands in Haskell

Tags: shell, haskell, sudo

I am having ghc 6.12.3 and Ubuntu 11.04 installed on my laptop.

I would like to have a function which take some shell commands and execute them as the superuser (like sudo update-manager, sudo iwlist ....) in Haskell. I know that the System.Process module have some functions like createProcess, runInteractiveCommand. But there are for a single raw command or a single shell command, not for compound commnads like "sudo update-manager". All my experiments on those functions to execute "sudo ..." failed. The terminal I used to run my haskell function had no response.

I also looked at HSH package. But it seems to me that functions exported there are not good for sudo commands either.

My guess is that executing commands like "sudo update-manager" requires two process. One is for "sudo" and the other one is for "update-manager". So I need to call functions like "createProcess" twice and somehow connect them so that the second process for "update-manager" get superuser privilege from the first process for "sudo".

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: `updateManager` is an argument to `sudo`.`sudo` is going to read all it's arguments and creates a new commandline out of them.

Comment: Show us the code you tried that didn't work. From your description, it should have worked.

Comment: Thats probably not a good idea. Better is to drop your level instead of elevating it

Answer (score 13):

Try `readProcess` from `System.Process`

> ```
> readProcess :: FilePath -- command to run 
> -> [String]             -- any arguments 
> -> String               -- standard input 
> -> IO String            -- stdout
> ```
>
> `readProcess` forks an external process, reads its standard output
>   strictly, blocking until the process terminates, and returns the
>   output string.

Run it like this:

```
readProcess "/usr/bin/sudo" ("-S":someProgram) (passwort++"\n")
```

This executes `sudo` with the options `-S` and the program. `-S` is needed to read the password from stdin. The password must finish with a newline, so the program adds one.

Answer (score 8):

Answering the last paragraph. `sudo` is a regular program, no magic whatsoever. It just happens to run other programs. So does your Haskell program. Your program runs `sudo` and `sudo` runs `update-manager` So no, you should not create two processes.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried System.Process.system?

```
import System.Process

main = system "sudo update-manager"
```

This works for me (GHC 7.0.3). Also, for scripting in Haskell in general (sudo included), you can have a look at a presentation ["Practical Haskell: scripting with types"](http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2010/08/17/practical-haskell/) by Don Stewart.

Comment: This fails when there is no shell.

Comment: Code from the presentation is available at https://github.com/mbezjak/playground/tree/master/scripting-with-types